# How do I test an object to see if it can still recieve messages to avoid EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective C, what is a good way to test if an object is in memory?

Ive been using code like this:

```
if(myObject){
    [myObject stop];
}
```

But despite this, I still keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors on the line that runs the stop message on `myObject`.

Can anybody suggest a better way of testing if `myObject` is still around and capable of receiving messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObject` is pointing to garbage right now, so it will be sent a message and the app will crash, because it is not the object you think it is anymore.

If you want to check whether it can receive a certain message you can use:

```
if ( [myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(mySelector)] ){ ....
```

Or setting it to nil properly and check whether the pointer still points to an object elsewhere using:

```
if ( myObject ){   ... //If myObject is not nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test in this way because all you really check is if the pointer is zero, which it is obviously not.

Look into ARC's weak references, which are zeroes automatically by the system once an object is deallocated.

What more, in a lot of cases, memory is reused and instead of bad access, you may get an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` exception. In that case, any possible `NSIsPointerStillValidForSendingSelectors(myObject)` would return `YES`, but still it would not be your object.

Comment: I don't want to create a weak reference to an object. I want to test if an object can still receive messages. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Jimmery: This is impossible. What you have is a *dangling pointer*, e.g. a pointer to some part in the memory where there might or might not be an object. Try to figure out why you've got a pointer to a deallocated object.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly do you think the `respondsToSelector:` will work?

Comment: @Jimmery: No. It is impossible. The solution to your problem is figuring out why the object got deallocated while you are still using it.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is with weak reference. It achieves exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid dangling pointer situation , you always make nil to object reference

```
[myObject release];

myObject = nil ;
```

then after that the below code will work as per your desire

```
if(myObject != nil)
{
    [myObject stop];
}
```

In fact, Objective-C automatically tests for `nil` when sending a message to an object, so the following is actually equivalent:

```
[myObject stop]; // If myObject is nil, this statement will not do anything.
```

Comment: I should of said that I am using ARC